# What does "<indentifier> expected" mean?

Tags: java, bluej

I am making Robot Soccer.
I have 4 classes

- Game
- Robot
- Ball
- Point

`Game` is supposed to hold the main method, however this is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Game{
        public Robot;
        public Ball;
        public Point;

        public static void main(String[]args){
           Point field= new Point();
           Point end = new Point();
           field.x=10;
           field.y=10;
           end.x=10;
           end.y=0;



        }

    }
```

For Point I have:

```
public class Point{
   public int x;
   public int y;
}
```

But in `Ball` and `Robot` I get an identifier error when I I set initial positions for the ball and robot objects:
Ball:

```
public class  Ball{

    class Ball{
        Ball fifa= newBall();
        Point fifa= newPoint();
        int speed=1;
        fifa.x= 5;
        fifa.y= 5;
    }


    public void moveUp(){
        fifa.y=y-1;

    }
    public void moveDown(){
        fifa.y++;

    }
    public void moveLeft(){
        fifa.x--;


    }
    public void moveRight(){
        fifa.x++;
    }
}
```

Robot:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Robot{

   class Robot{

      Point d= newPoint();
      Point e= newPoint();
      Robot d= newRobot();
      Robot e= newRobot();
      int speed=1;
      d.x = 0;
      e.x =3;
      d.y = 1;
      e.y =5;
    }



    public void moveUp(){
        d.y=y-1;
        e.y=y-1;
    }
    public void moveDown(){
        d.y++;
        e.y++;
    }
    public void moveLeft(){
        d.x--;
        e.x--;

    }
    public void moveRight(){
        d.x++;
        e.x++;
    }
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Your `Ball` and `Robot` classes look like they might explode if you ever instantiate them. Each class is holding a reference to one or more objects of itself, which will be initialised when the class is first instantiated. This will cause each one of those objects to instantiate its own set of objects, which in turn will instantiate yet more objects and so on... This won't stop until you kill the program yourself or the JVM dies in a fiery OutOfMemoryError, whichever happens sooner. Not only that, but you can't hide an enclosing class with a nested class, so they won't even compile currently.

Answer (score 3):

You have not given the variable name for your objects.

change

```
    public Robot;
    public Ball;
    public Point;
```

to

```
    public Robot robot =null;
    public Ball ball=null;
    public Poin point =null;
```